# Rebuild failed: Dictionary key 12 is not a name. at file pointer 14875

Tags: c#, itext

I'm actually developing a program that needs to read various images of different formats, including PDF ones, and export them into a final PDF. But when I open a certain PDF (input, not the output one) the programs throws me the error in the title. The program exactly stops at this line:
var reader = new PdfReader(data);
Where data is a byte array in which is stored the file.

I managed to find the problem, in fact if I open the PDF with Notepad++ or a normal notepad, I can assume that the reader goes bad when it reads "/DA   /Helvetica 12 Tf 0 g ". What should I do to repare this PDF?

Comment: Please include a much bigger code snippet, ideally the method in which the opening logic is taking place, and please include the full error text

Answer (score 1):

The default appearance **DA** shall be mapped to the *default appearance **string** containing a sequence of valid page-content graphics or text state operators that define such properties as the field’s text size and colour.* In your PDF the generator apparently forgot that a **string** needs delimiters.

To repair the file, simply put the instructions in delimiters, e.g. replace

```
/DA /Helvetica 12 Tf 0 g
```

by

```
/DA (/Helvetica 12 Tf 0 g)
```

This of course is two bytes longer. If you repair with a text editor and don't want to fix all the cross references of objects thereafter, drop the `0 g` (which is default anyways) and replace by

```
/DA (/Helvetica 12 Tf  )
```

---

You commented

> I tried with both but when I then open the PDF with Acrobat or any other reader, I just see a corrupted PDF

so we arranged for you sending the PDF in question to me for analysis.

As it turned out, the situation was worse than you thought.

First of all, there was not only one occurrence of the issue you had identified, there were seven of them.

Furthermore, the issue actually was a bit different than you saw in a text editor, there were some additional nul bytes the editor did not show you but which leap at the eye when inspecting the data using a hex editor, e.g.

[image: Screen shot]

Thus, there was enough space to add delimiters without having to drop an instruction:

[image: Screen shot]

With all the 7 occurrences fixed you tested again and found out

> Now it works

Beware, though, there are other issues in the file, too.

For example, there are other **DA** values that also are broken, e.g.:

```
/DA /Helvetica#2012#20Tf#200#20g
```

The value of **DA** is specified to be a string, not a name. Thus, this is incorrect

Comment: I tried with both but when I then open the PDF with Acrobat or any other reader, I just see a corrupted PDF

Comment: You have made sure not to damage binary content in the editor? For example, by using the hex editor plugin of Notepad++? And if you have, maybe there are other errors in the PDF to start with. Please share the PDF for analysis.

Comment: It's a company private PDF, so it's better if I share it only with you. How can I send it?

Comment: Ok, I received your mail and look into that PDF.

Comment: @Chexet48 Have you received my answer and checked the attached document?

Comment: Yes, yesterday I received your e-mail and tried to work again with your PDF. Now it works, I can't thank you enough

Comment: Great! I updated the answer to contain the full repair needed.